# Please help me improve this sentence: I have involved many activities. This includes attending conference A, conference B

Tags: sentence, expression-choice

Please help me improve this sentence:

> I have involved many activities.  **This includes** attending conference A, conference B....

Not sure if I should use "These include" or "This includes".

Answer (score 1):

The reader will most likely assume that you are going on to talk about your activities, so I'd lean towards "these include". I'd suggest altering the first sentence, too:

> I have been involved in many activities. These include attending conference A, conference B …